# Why modify an Array of objects don't change my objects?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have DataRow from grid and I need to modify few columns in one row. So I put all my columns in Array, and tried to modify them but it doesn't work as I wish. I need an explanation for that.

My goal is to get all columns in specific order in Array or some collection, and then modify them etc. I think I am now creating some new objects which reference to something else than my column. Maybe I should try to store in collection some references? Using ref should is best option?

```
DataRow dr = rows[i] as DataRow;
dr["size"] = 5000; // => size is 5000;
ChangeSize(dr); // => size is 6000;
```

## ChangeSize body

```
private void ChangeSize(DataRow dataRow)
{
             dataRow["size"] = 6000; // => size is 6000
             Object[] arrayOfColumns= { dataRow["size"], ... };
             arrayOfColumns[0] = 7000; // => won't change size...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *just* changing the value in the array. You happened to initialize that via `dataRow["size"]` but that doesn't mean there's any perpetual link between the two.

If you need changes to be reflected back to the `DataRow`, I suspect you should have another method to do that:

```
private void CopyToDataRow(Object[] source, DataRow target)
{
    target["size"] = source[0];
    // etc
}
```

There's no concept of triggering custom code like this whenever an array is modified - you'll need to call it at the appropriate time. (And no, `ref` wouldn't help you here at all.)

Comment: I use that method in my application. It's good to hear that ref won't help.

Answer (score 1):

dataRow["size"] contains an int which is a value type.

When you instanciate and intialize arrayOfColumns you get a copy of the value contained at dataRow["size"] and not a reference.

Comment: Is there any way to initialize Array with ref to that object? Or I should just copy the value like Jon Skeet write below?

Comment: In that case, you can't use ref. As Jon Skeet noticed, you should use an extra method to update the value